# Not able to get location offline(Without Wifi or mobile net) using FusedLocationApi

Tags: android, android-location

I am trying to get user current location even without wifi or mobile net using FusedLocationApi.

How can I achieve this with fused location API.?

Location manager has this functionality, I don't want to use location manager as in fuse location i am getting a most accurate result so, How can I achieve this so let me post what I tried so far

refer to below code

```
   mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(300);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        PendingResult<Status> statusPendingResult = 
   LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, new LocationCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult result) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onLocationResult" + result.getLastLocation().getLatitude() + " " + result.getLastLocation().getLongitude());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLocationAvailability(LocationAvailability locationAvailability) {

                            Log.d("TAG", "onLocationAvailability: isLocationAvailable =  " + locationAvailability.isLocationAvailable());
                        }
                    }, null);

                    statusPendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Status status) {
                            if (status.getStatus().isSuccess()) {

                                Log.d("TAG", "Successfully requested location updates");

                            } else {

                                CommonMethods.setAddress("Couldn't find the location");
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Couldn't get the location. Make sure location is enabled on the device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                Log.e("TAG",
                                        "Failed in requesting location updates, "
                                                + "status code: "
                                                + status.getStatusCode() + ", message: " + status
                                                .getStatusMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

by adding this line

```
mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(300);
```

you realize that the difference distance between the two locations should be 300 meters did you try to cover the distance that far?

try to remove it

Comment: I had tried also with displacement 0 but still no luck.